# something in the CSS - possibly flexbox - isn't working

Tags: html, css, flexbox

https://codepen.io/andrewdstrain/pen/mdbaVex

The issue I'm talking about is when the width of the viewing window shows the navigation (menu) button on the upper right.

I'm using flexbox to create a navigational header. The CSS renders properly in Safari, Firefox, Chrome, and Edge on Windows, macOS, and Android. But iOS (iPhone) - it almost renders properly. iOS just overlays the section element overtop the header element.

At first, I thought that it was the flexbox stuff. But adding in `-webkit-` stuff doesn't seem to change anything. Not only that, but iOS is rendering the flexbox CSS - just try changing it and it will reflect the changes.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>FlexBox Header</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css" media="screen">
</head>

<body id="index" class="home">
        <header id="banner" class="body">
                <a href="#" class="site-name">FlexBox Header</a>
                <input type="checkbox" id="menu-button-input">
                <label id="menu-button" for="menu-button-input"><span class="icon-bar">&#9776;</span></label>
                <nav id="menu"><div class="container top-menu">
                    <div class="container-item active"><a href="#">Home</a></div>
                    <div class="container-item"><a href="#">Categories</a></div>
                    <div class="container-item"><a href="#">Archive</a></div>
                </div></nav><!-- /#menu -->
        </header><!-- /#banner -->
<section id="content">
<h2>All articles</h2>

<ol id="post-list">
        <li><article class="hentry">
                <header> <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="#" rel="bookmark" title="Permalink to Dude, You're Getting a Dell">Dude, You're Getting a Dell</a></h2> </header>
                <footer class="post-info">
                    <time class="published" datetime="2019-03-06T19:00:00-05:00"> 2019-03-06 </time>
                    <address class="vcard author">By
                        <a class="url fn" href="#">Blaztek</a>
                    </address>
                </footer><!-- /.post-info -->
                <div class="entry-content"> <p class="first last">My first experience with Dell customer service.</p>
 </div><!-- /.entry-content -->
        </article></li>
        <li><article class="hentry">
                <header> <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="#" rel="bookmark" title="Permalink to How To Find The Python Version Number">How To Find The Python Version Number</a></h2> </header>
                <footer class="post-info">
                    <time class="published" datetime="2019-02-26T08:27:00-05:00"> 2019-02-26 </time>
                    <address class="vcard author">By
                        <a class="url fn" href="#">Blaztek</a>
                    </address>
                </footer><!-- /.post-info -->
                <div class="entry-content"> <p class="first last">How to find the Python version number.</p>
 </div><!-- /.entry-content -->
        </article></li>
        <li><article class="hentry">
                <header> <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="#" rel="bookmark" title="Permalink to First Post">First Post</a></h2> </header>
                <footer class="post-info">
                    <time class="published" datetime="2019-02-24T10:16:00-05:00"> 2019-02-24 </time>
                    <address class="vcard author">By
                        <a class="url fn" href="#">Blaztek</a>
                    </address>
                </footer><!-- /.post-info -->
                <div class="entry-content"> <p>What are you doing that is geeky? What am I doing that is geeky? Geek
activities that I do are posted whenever I get the chance. Please check back
periodically to see what's new.</p>
 </div><!-- /.entry-content -->
        </article></li>
</ol><!-- /#posts-list -->
</section><!-- /#content -->
        <footer id="contentinfo" class="body">
                <address id="about" class="vcard body">
                Proudly powered by <a href="http://getpelican.com/">Pelican</a>,
                which takes great advantage of <a href="http://python.org">Python</a>.
                </address><!-- /#about -->
        </footer><!-- /#contentinfo -->
<script>
window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
  document.getElementById('menu-button-input').checked = false;
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**index.css**

```
/*
 * CSS for the skeleton of the upper header
 */

.home {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#banner {
  align-items: baseline;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#banner #menu-button-input {
  display: none;
}

#banner #menu {
  display: none;
}
#banner #menu .container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  list-style: none;
}

#banner #menu-button-input:checked ~ #menu {
  display: block;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 48em) {
  #banner {
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: flex-start;
  }

  #banner #menu-button {
    display: none;
  }

  #banner #menu {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
  #banner #menu .container {
    flex-direction: row;
  }
}



/*
 * CSS for the theme's visual styles
 */

.home {
  color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.875em;
  margin: 0em;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

header, section {
  padding: 0em 1.25em;
}

a {
  color: rgb(56, 117, 215);
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* from elegant.css */
.site-name {
  font-family: "Monaco", "Inconsolata", "Andale Mono", "Lucida Console", "Bitstream Vera Sans Mono", "Courier New", Courier, Monospace;
}

#banner {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgb(255, 255, 255), rgb(242, 242, 242));
  border: 0.0625em solid rgb(212, 212, 212);
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0980392) 0em 0.0625em 0.625em;
}

#banner a {
  color: rgb(119, 119, 119);
}

#banner a.site-name {
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  padding: 0.625em 0em;
  text-shadow: rgb(255, 255, 255) 0px 0.0625em 0px;
}

#banner #menu-button {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgb(242, 242, 242), rgb(229, 229, 229));
  border: 0.0625em solid rgb(204, 204, 204);
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  border-radius: 0.25em;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0.0625em 0 rgba(255,255,255,.1), 0 0.0625em 0 rgba(255,255,255,.075);
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  font-size: 1.1875em;
  height: 1.625em;
  position: relative;
  right: 0.375em;
  text-align: center;
  top: -0.125em;
  width: 2.3125em;
}

#banner #menu-button .icon-bar {
  position: relative;
  top: 0.125em;
}

#banner #menu {
  width: 100%;
}

#banner #menu .top-menu .container-item a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0.9375em;
  text-shadow: 0 0.0625em 0 rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

#banner #menu .top-menu .container-item.active a {
  background-color: rgb(229, 229, 229);
  border-radius: 0.1875em;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0.1875em 0.5em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
  color: rgb(55,55,55);
}

/*
 * elegant.css
 *
 * .top-menu li a
 */
.top-menu .container-item a {
  font-weight: bold;
}

footer {
  padding: 0em 0.1875em;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 48em) {
  header {
    padding: 0em 3em;
  }
  section {
    padding: 0% 20% 0% 25%;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are giving a `min-height` to the #banner

add this style  to your CSS

```
#banner {
min-height: 45px;
align-items: center;
}
```

Updated solution: https://jsfiddle.net/7tyrhxbd/

Comment: I'm not using the min-height **but** the jsfiddle site does display the document with the problem - just like iOS does - even on Windows desktop at least.

Answer (score 0):

There are two different things that screw this up. That is, fix one of them (not both), and the problem is solved.

## First

I found that there is a problem with this block of CSS:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

It's the `html` tag that screws things up in iOS. When I get rid of it, iOS displays just like the other operating systems do.

I was using that block to keep the footer always down at the bottom.

### Second

The other problem is with this (class `.home` is only on the `body` element):

```
.home {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

If I remove the flexbox, it works. Again, the footer isn't always at the bottom anymore - but that's not too difficult to fix.

### My Solution

My code was treating the `body` tag as a `div` element. So I decided to actually make a wrapper element. This allows for an easy way to get the footer to actually always be at the bottom of the page. It also allows for a column flexbox for the main elements to be maintained - even though there doesn't seem to be any good reason for this. I'll probably end up taking it out.

The fix can be seen here:

https://jsfiddle.net/blaztek/fr59t86q/